# How to use NSSM

Tags: windows, service, windows-8, exe, nssm

This is probably glaringly obvious, but how do I "install" NSSM? according to the docs, I don't need to. If I wanted to use the GUI, I know that works (I've tested that) but when using cmd prompt or a batch file, it can't find it.

I know that the docs say "...preferably somewhere in your PATH", but I'm not sure where that would be. (neither of the "program files" folders work.)

Comment: At a command prompt, type `set PATH` and hit ENTER. Those are the folders that are "somewhere on your PATH".

Comment: @KenWhite I have already tried placing in my "program files (x86)" which is the first folder in said path.

Comment: `Program Files (x86)` is not typically in the PATH (for a good reason). You should probably check that again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place the nssm.exe file in a folder, which is already on your PATH variable

Use `echo %PATH%` or `set PATH` on the CLI to find out the folders.

OR

Place into `C:\Programs\nssm` and then add this folder to your PATH env variable:

`setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Programs\nssm" /M`

For usage, consult the manual: [CLI](http://nssm.cc/commands) and [GUI](http://nssm.cc/usage)